# How to order/sort my collections / relationships?

Tags: jhipster

I've just started using Jhipster for a simple project with a very simple datamodel (so far). 
I have a question regarding the generated code for the one-to-many relationship:

Is it possible to generate with List instead of a Set, so I can have my child-items ordered?

If no, what is the best solution to solve my problem? I see 2 ways:

1. Change the generated code manually to use a List and then use liquibase (mvn liquibase:diff) to update my database ?
2. Have an attribute on the child-item to handle the order ?

What is the best way to handle the "problem" ?

Best regards 
Martin Elkkjær

Comment: You can se my model here - issue is Competition->Round:https://jhipster.github.io/jdl-studio/#/view/%0Aentity%20Competition%20%7B%0A%09name%20String%0A%7D%0A%0Aentity%20Pilot%7B%0A%09name%20String%0A%7D%0A%0Aentity%20Flight%7B%0A%09duration%20Long%0A%20%20%20%20landing%20Long%0A%20%20%20%20penalty%20Long%0A%7D%0A%0Aentity%20Round%20%7B%0A%09startTime%20ZonedDateTime%0A%7D%0A%0Arelationship%20OneToMany%20%7B%0A%09Competition%7Bround%7D%20to%20Round,%0A%20%20%20%20Round%7Bflight%7D%20to%20Flight%7Bround%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Arelationship%20OneToOne%7B%0A%09Flight%7Bpilot%7D%20to%20Pilot%0A%7D

Comment: If I remember correctly, there's a section on ordering in JHipster (free) mini book by  Matt Raible.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Spring `@OrderBy` annotation to sort your sets by the child entity.  See http://www.objectdb.com/api/java/jpa/OrderBy

```
@Entity 
public class Person {
     ...
   @OrderBy("zipcode.zip, zipcode.plusFour")
   public Set<Address> getResidences() {...};
   ...
}
```

I'd also recommend the following blog that explains how Sets/Lists differ for Hibernate and JPA: https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-facts-favoring-sets-vs-bags/ (where I found the answer originally)